# Russia Visa application by mail

Tags: visas, russia

I'm applying for a tourist visa to Russia from Los Angeles. I will have to mail my application somewhere.

1. Does it matter which of the ILS offices I apply to?
2. Should I use a third-party to get this done or can I just mail it in myself. It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: It sounds like you already are planning to use a third party service. You can do it yourself [here](https://visa.kdmid.ru/).

Comment: Fair point but to get a visa using the link you provide requires me to do it in person. The ILS offices seem to be somewhere in between the embassy and a third-party. For example, they are an option from the dropdowns on the russian visa application website.

Comment: OK, yes, they are kind of semi-official. I didn't see anything about having to visit a consulate in person, though, but if it told you that, then perhaps you should just use ILS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does it matter which of the ILS offices I apply to?

Theoretically, no.
Practically, check reviews before, and pay attention to medium/maximum awaiting time.

2. Should I use a third-party to get this done or can I just mail it in myself. It seems pretty straightforward.

ILS is already *kind of* third-party so you don't need another one (you you care about spending your money on something useful).

Comment: My passport and visa is on the way back to me from the embassy. Took a couple of weeks total. There were a couple of issues with my application and ILS called me to help me fix them. Great process overall.